# C#.NET Winform in unmanaged C++ via CLI wrapper - thread required?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c++-cli

I am trying to make a program where I call a C#.NET Form from unmanaged C++ via a C++/CLI wrapper class.

The form displays as expected, but any code after launch of the form does not execute.  I don't really understand threading, but I feel that may be my issue.

Here's my main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    int  fred;
    TestFormWrapper testForm;   

    testForm.ShowForm();

    std::cin >> fred;  // to allow me to see the form before and after label change

    testForm.ChangeLabel(); 

    std::cin >> fred;  // to allow me to see the form before and after label change

    return 0;

}
```

And here's my CLI Wrapper:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) TestFormWrapper
{
private:
    TestFormWrapperPrivate* _private;

public:
    TestFormWrapper()
    {
        _private = new TestFormWrapperPrivate();
        _private->testForm = gcnew ManagedForms::TestForm();

    }

    ~TestFormWrapper()
    {
        delete _private;
    }


    void ShowForm()
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::Application::Run(_private->testForm);
    }

    void ChangeLabel()
    {
        _private->testForm->changeLabel();
        _private->testForm->Refresh();
    }   

};
```

My console, where I enter numbers in order to progress execution, will not allow any input until I close my form. What I'm actually aiming for here is for the form to update while other code is executing, e.g. showing data from the main program thread.

Any ideas?

Comment: You inverted the threads - the UI always runs on a foreground thread (which is typically considered the main thread), other work occurs on background threads.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks. I'm VERY unfamiliar with threading, is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: A UI thread is a UI thread because it runs a message loop.  That loop is `Application::Run`.  It doesn't matter whether the process main thread becomes a UI thread or a worker thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you don't have any multi-threading at all.

The C++ processing thread can't continue until the C# function it calls, returns.  So that C# function should start a new thread and return quickly.

The new thread can then activate a message loop (`Application::Run`) and show UI.

You will need to use `Control::Invoke()` to access UI from other threads.  Hopefully it is the C# portion of the code doing that -- anonymous lambdas and such get it done in a lot less code than you would need with C++.